# Check if Record Exists IN DB Using ASP VB

Tags: asp.net, sql, vb.net

I am trying to check whether an email exists in my sql database from an an asp code behind

Basically a user will fill in a form and submit, I need to check wther that email exists first before inserting

```
 Protected Sub btnSignup_Click(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnSignup.Click
    Response.Cookies("survey")("fullname") = TextBoxFullName.Text
    Response.Cookies("survey")("surname") = TextBoxSurname.Text
    Response.Cookies("survey")("lastVisit") = DateTime.Now.ToString()
    Response.Cookies("survey")("contactnumber") = TextBoxPhone.Text
    Response.Cookies("survey")("email") = TextBoxEmail.Text
    Response.Cookies("survey").Expires = DateTime.Now.AddDays(365)


    'InsertCommand="INSERT INTO [Comp_20140409_Broadband] ([SignupName], [SignupGender], [SignupIDNo], [SignupEmailAddress], [CurrentProvider], [CurrentSpeed], [CurrentUsage]) VALUES (@SignupName, @SignupGender, @SignupIDNo, @SignupEmailAddress, @CurrentProvider, @CurrentSpeed, @CurrentUsage)" 
    If Not Page.IsValid Then Exit Sub


    Dim connectionString As String = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings("ConnectionString").ConnectionString
    Dim updateSql3 As String = "Select [PersonId] FROM  [Users] WHERE [Email] = @Email"
    Dim PersonId As Integer
    Using myConnection As New SqlConnection(connectionString)
        myConnection.Open()
        Dim myCommand As New SqlCommand(updateSql3, myConnection)
        myCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Email", TextBoxEmail.Text)
        PersonId = myCommand.ExecuteScalar()



        myConnection.Close()
        End Using



        Dim updateSql2 As String = " INSERT INTO [Survey_Legal] ([LegalInsurance],[ThirdParty], [LegalIssues], [RequestLegal], [PersonId], [Category_Type]) VALUES (@LegalInsurance, @ThirdParty, @LegalIssues, @RequestLegal, @PersonId, @Type )"

        Using myConnection2 As New SqlConnection(connectionString)
        myConnection2.Open()
        Dim myCommand2 As New SqlCommand(updateSql2, myConnection2)
        myCommand2.Parameters.AddWithValue("@LegalInsurance", DDLLegal1.SelectedValue)
        myCommand2.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ThirdParty", DDLLegal2.SelectedValue)
        myCommand2.Parameters.AddWithValue("@LegalIssues", DDLLegal3.SelectedValue)
        myCommand2.Parameters.AddWithValue("@RequestLegal", DDLLegal4.SelectedValue)
        myCommand2.Parameters.AddWithValue("@PersonId", PersonId)
        myCommand2.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Type", "Legal-Insurance")




        myCommand2.ExecuteNonQuery()
        myConnection2.Close()
    End Using
```

Comment: This is not Classic ASP.

Comment: @Paul The phrase *"code behind"* is a big give away.

Comment: @Lankymart - Oh! I realise that, but it's like people getting confused with Java and JavaScript...

Comment: I actually sorted it out, thanks anyway Paul

Answer (score 0):

This is how I do this.  I check for a duplicate email address in my stored procedure with an output parameter.

```sql
CREATE Procedure sp_AddSubscriber 
    @Name as nvarchar(50), 
    @Email as nvarchar(50), 
    @AddSubscriber bit OUTPUT

AS

IF (SELECT COUNT(Email) 
    FROM TSubscribers 
    WHERE Email = @Email) = 0

    BEGIN 
        INSERT TSubscribers (Name, Email)  
        VALUES (@Name, @Email)
        SET @AddSubscriber = False                          
    END
ELSE
   SET @AddSubscriber = True

GO
```